# Quantum teleportation between two computer chips, how relevant?

Tags: teleportation

After stumbling upon this recent news article: [Information teleported between two computer chips for the first time](https://newatlas.com/quantum-computing/quantum-teleportation-computer-chips) (which references a "Nature Physics" publication [Chip-to-chip quantum teleportation and multi-photon entanglement in silicon](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-019-0727-x))...

> ...with quantum teleportation, information appears to break that speed limit
>
> Harnessing this phenomenon could clearly be beneficial, and the new study helps bring that closer to reality. The team generated pairs of entangled photons on the chips, and then made a quantum measurement of one. This observation changes the state of the photon, and those changes are then instantly applied to the partner photon in the other chip.

... I've been wondering what this specific break-through means for the state of quantum teleportation, if anything.

The quotes above would appear to imply that information *can* potentially be transported and used instantly, faster than the speed of light. Is that accurate though? My understanding was that because of its dependency on classical communication, quantum teleportation won't allow for faster-than-light communication in practice. Has that changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information can't be transmitted faster-than-light using quantum teleportation protocol, because as you correctly noticed quantum teleportation involves classical communication between sender and receiver.

The paper's abstract is saying about implementing quantum teleportation using a particular technology (silicon integrated optics) for the first time. This is probably great, but it has nothing to do with faster-than-light communication.

Comment: So I guess the "information appears to break that speed limit" part in the New Atlas article is kinda misleading then?

Comment: This is popular wrong interpretation of Einstein's "spooky action at distance".